# Webpack: SyntaxError: Unexpected token error when trying to access JSON array

Tags: javascript, json

I am importing `.json` from `.js` file: `import pca from './pca.js'`. Using `console.log()` outputs correct `JSON` in the console, but when I am trying to access it in code

```
pca_json = JSON.parse(pca); (I can remove parsing, not working either) 
pca_json["rowname"].forEach(...
```

webpack fails with an error:

[image]

I tried changing extention: `.js -> .json` but it fails to import the file at all in that case giving me another error:

[image]

The `pca.js` (or `pca.json`) looks like that:

```
var pca = {
    "rowname" : [
        "Ciliated_sensory_neurons",
        "Touch_receptor_neurons",
         ...
         ...
    ]
}
export default pca
```

I tried importing `pca.json` using `fs` module but it is not working either. I am getting the error: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7384

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your file is JS, not JSON, so it should end in `.js`.

Comment: Calling `JSON.parse` makes no sense, since you don't have a string.

Comment: As the error is trying to tell you, your syntax in the calling file is invalid.  The "JSON" has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Why can't I access the JSON object by its key? It is the correct syntax

Comment: In the middle of a variable declaration?

Comment: OK, I think I see

Comment: Yep, wrong ',' at the end of `shapes`. Works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is Javascript. Not JSON. JSON is just a string. Anything with `var` in it is Javascript. The issue is with your javascript code in `datumScatterChart.js` after you import it. Not with the file you are importing.

You are attempting to do a `forEach` inside a variable declaration. Change `datumScatterChart.js` to look like this...

```
var data = [], shapes = [...];

pca_json["rowname"].forEach(function () { ... });
```

Notice the semicolon after the variable declartion and before the `forEach` loop. This is exactly what the error message is telling you `Unexpected token , expected ;`